# Compile an existing js file azure web app using visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, azure

I had an Azure mobile service api's that recently migrated into web app.
I used to code directly via the browser (which was very easy).

Due to the migration I am now able to view the api's/ files only via visual studio - I view it directly from the server.

I need to change one of the api's/ files. I've simply updated it and saved (I got an indication saying this is saved in azure).
BUT - when calling the api I don't get the new functionality. I've also added a console log to check if the new code is running.
How do I get the new code to work (do I need to compile/ build)?

Note that I don't have a project and I've never deployed it before (all the help I've found is related to existing project). The migration from mobile services to web app was done automatically in Azure.

Would appreciate any help/ direction. All I need is a way to compile it I guess..
Thanks
Tal

Comment: Could you paste the `web.config` file content into your question?

Comment: Hi Aaron Chen
It is a generic Azure web.config file but it is too big to be added here..
I'm only implementing API's so I didn't change it, it was generated automatically as part of the mobile service to web app migration.

Comment: Are you using node.js as a backend?

Comment: I think so, I have app.js and application.json files

Comment: Basically, you don't need to compile/build js file. You could double check whether the js file is updated from Azure App service through Kudu Debug Console which could be accessed via `https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

Comment: When I save it in Visual Studio I do get a message stating that the changes are applied in Microsoft Azure but when I call the api via REST I can see that the changes are not applied.
A workaround that I've found is to work directly via Azure "easy API" option. There I can see that the file is updated but it is applied only after I click the "run" button on the right bar.  Is there any parallel function in visual studio?

Comment: I've meant the "left" bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Visual Studio expert, but maybe you can add the following line into the `web.config` file to let IISNODE recycle the site whenever the web.config changes or any .js files.

```
<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
```

For more information, you can refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps.